# Showing the time of another time zone

Tags: javascript, time, timezone, momentjs

I am Creating a Page which must show, UTC time, My Current time and Other / Country / Timezone Time. I use moment.min.js, moment-timezone.js, jquery.min.js - I used - http://www.digitoffee.com/programming/get-local-time-utc-using-moment-js/94/. Please help me to get the time of another timezone. - Here is the code in jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/shejus/g63d2onw/10/ - Please help

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DISPLAY TIME</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        UTC
        <br/>
        <div id="divUTC"></div>
        <br/>
Your Local Time with respect to above UTC time
        <br/>
        <div id="divLocal"></div>
        <br/>
OTHER TIMEZONE TIME
        <br/>
        <div id="anyutctime"></div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script>
    $(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    var divUtc = $('#divUTC');
    var divLocal = $('#divLocal');
    var anyutctime = $ ('#anyutctime');

    //put UTC time into divUTC  
    divUtc.text(moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));      

    //get text from divUTC and conver to local timezone  
    var localTime  = moment.utc(divUtc.text()).toDate();
    localTime = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    divLocal.text(localTime);        
  },1000);

    //Display time of Another timezone 
     var anyTime  = moment.utc(divUtc.text()).toDate();
    anyTime = moment.tz("America/Chicago").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    anyutctime.text(anyTime);        
});
    </script>
        <script src="js/moment-timezone.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several errors:

- Your fiddle isn't loading all of the resources you specified.

  - jQuery isn't loading because you provided a `http` URL, and the fiddle is loaded via `https`.  As a rule of thumb, specify [protocol-relative URLs](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) when loading external resources on jsFiddle. (start the URL with `//`, leaving off any `http:` or `https:`).
  - You're loading moment-timezone before moment.  Per the moment-timezone documentation, you need to load moment *first*.  Moment-timezone hooks into the moment global.
- You didn't provide any time zone data to moment-timezone.  You can either manually load data for specific time zone(s) using `moment.tz.add`, or you can use one of the pre-populated data files, such as `moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js`.  You use this file *instead of* the `moment-timezone.min.js` file (it includes both script and data).
- You had a `<body>` tag in your HTML snippet. This is not required in a jsFiddle.
- You had some of the script outside the scope of the inner function being called by `setInterval`.  That was causing `divUtc` to be undefined on first run, and the "other time zone time" not being populated.  Watch the closing brackets carefully.

With the above items addressed, your code works just fine.  [Updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/g63d2onw/11/).

However, you still have some unnecessary operations in your script.  In general, there's no need to use div contents, strings, or `Date` objects as intermediate state holders.  In fact, because you're not doing anything else with the moment object, you can just create it once and mutate the state before each display.  (If you were doing further operations, you might want to *clone* it first.)

[The fully optimized jsFiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/g63d2onw/12/), and the code is as follows:

```
$(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    var divUtc = $('#divUTC');
    var divLocal = $('#divLocal');
    var divOther = $('#divOther');

    var format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';

    // get current local time
    var now = moment();

    // display the local time
    divLocal.text(now.format(format));

    // switch to utc mode and display
    divUtc.text(moment.utc().format(format));      

    // switch to another time zone and display
    divOther.text(now.tz('America/Chicago').format(format));
  },1000);
});
```

Lastly, I'll just comment that in general you should try to ask more specific questions on Stack Overflow, rather than just looking for general debugging help.  Stack Overflow is primarily about providing useful re-usable questions and answers that will help *others* in addition to helping you with this specific problem.  Next time, please follow the guidance in the following articles from the Stack Overflow help center:

- [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you sir :) you helped me this... God bless you